# Laravel $requst->all() method returns an empty array

Tags: php, laravel

JavaScript

```
this.request('post', `${controller_url}/update/${id}/${this.updated_row.title}/${this.updated_row.description}`)
```

Route:

```php
Route::post('/categories/update/{id}/{title}/{description}', 'CategoryController@update');
```

Controller:

```
public function update( Request $request, $id, $title, $description)
{
    var_dump($id);
    dd($request->all());
}
```

Result:

```
string(2) "81"
[]
```

I am wondering why `$request->all()` returns an empty array while `var_dump($id)` returns a value?

Comment: What is the form action?

Comment: It's an inline POST, not using a form

Comment: The url parameters are not the same as the resquest parameters. Try with `http://yourdomain/categories/update/2/some-title/some-description?request_parameter=some%request%parameter`

Comment: Isn't there anything in $ request because all URLs are passed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

id is coming as a URL not as a query params or request body. Your route is reading it in the URL. If you pass it as a `?id=81` you will get it.

Comment: Per this https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests#retrieving-input, I should be fine

Comment: But id is not input. May I know which line you are referring to.

Comment: If I can't get all the values using the `all()`, method what can I do to get all the values?

Comment: Or perhaps I am don't know how the Request Class works

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior, as Laravel does not consider `{id}/{title}/{description}` as `input`.
so all of these will be `null`

```php
$request->input('id')
$request->input('title')
$request->input('description')
```

and `$request->all()` just gets all the `input()` values plus `files`. So, the array should be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Route parameters are not "input". `$request->all()` is basically `$request->input()` plus files.

The dynamic property on Request, `$request->somevar` has a "fallback" to using a route parameter, but will use the input first.